# How do I implement bulma-calendar js events function in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, bulma

From the bulma extension docs, it says

**"The extension comes with a JavaScript implementation to handle the DatePicker input."**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var datePickers = bulmaCalendar.attach('[type="date"]', {
    overlay: true,
    minDate: '2018-01-01',
    maxDate: '2018-12-31'
  });
  // datePickers now contains an Array of all datePicker instances
  // To use Events API jus add a listener like below:
  // datepickerInstance.on(event, function(datepicker) {});
});
```

As a noob in both js and angular, I'm unable to translate it to angular and use the said function.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Adapting a pure JS library to be used like one would expect it to be used naturally in Angular is not an easy task and for large libraries requires weeks or months of work.

Comment: I see, thanks sir! To those who will encounter the same problem (using bulma calendar on angular for events), this might be a good alternative. https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="date" calendar>

app.directive("calendar", ["$timeout", "loading", function ($timeout, loading) 
{
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        var options = {
            showHeader: false,
            displayMode: 'dialog',
            minDate: '2018-09-30'
        }
        var calendars = bulmaCalendar.attach(angular.element($element)[0], options);

      }
    };
}]);
```